# Negative silhouette width in clustering

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have some clusters having observations below 0 Si (showing that they are not in a right cluster I assume). I am doing hierarchal clustering on a binary data. One of the solutions I found was reassign these rows to the neighbouring clusters and re-run until you have positive Si. Any suggestions for negative Si and also, how to reassign the values to different cluster?

`Aggl_clust<-eclust(Cluster, hc_metric="binary", FUNcluster = "hclust", k=6, hc_method = "complete", graph = FALSE)`

`fviz_dend(Aggl_clust, show_labels = FALSE, palette = "jco", as.ggplot = TRUE)`

`fviz_silhouette(Aggl_clust, palette = "jco", ggtheme = theme_classic())`

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: "how to reassign the values to different cluster?" Just put the object out from its cluster to the cluster that is another cluster nearest to this object. A good Silhouette index function should output you that cluster number.

Comment: The issue is I do not know how to change the place of the object (new to R). I just added my data frame as a picture so would be happy if you could suggest "how-to"

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ttnphns! I solved it